# Creating huge high-resolution Bitmap bigger than 23k x 23k

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I want to create a huge resolution Bitmap-image so that to load it into memory and transform it based on user-gestures.

I noticed that the limit for `new Bitmap(int32,int32);` is around 23000 but I need like 1159480 x 45920 with a bitdepth of 32.

Can someone help me out or is this impossible to do? I have 8 gigs of RAM.

Comment: That's impossible to do in memory. You would need 200GB of RAM for the bitmap. I would be surprised if there are any third-party libraries that would support such a large image.

Comment: `1159480 x 45920 x 4 =~ 200 GB`

Comment: I calculate your specified dimensions (1159480 by 45920) and bit-depth (4 bytes per pixel) to require about 210GB. That's rather a lot bigger than your available RAM. Are you sure you need to load it all into memory at once?

Comment: Even if it would be possible to have such an amount of ram and everything: A graphics card cannot handle so large images. It would not be possible to draw it at all... not even zoomed out. So what's the point of an image that cannot even be drawn?

Comment: Apparently this is a mission impossible, thanks anyway for the help. I'll try something else then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARE YOU REALLY SURE YOU NEED SUCH SIZE? It should be bigger than than **150GB**. Moreover if you consider a point size of 1/72 of inch your image will be <strike>409 km</strike> 500 m...

**EDITED** If you need a high resolution image of a large area you should consider to use **multiple** images with different resolutions (think Google Maps for example).

Comment: its 0.409km wide      http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281159480+%2F72%29+inches+to+km

Comment: and 0.0006626 km2 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281159480+x+45920%29+%2F%2872x72%29+square+inches+to+square+km  Thats the size of a Soccer Pitch - Is this the purpose of the APP?